# Mysql2: Getting Error : Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, operands

I am trying to create a following subquery and i get the error - Operand should contain 1 column(s).

```
select study_aid_id from study_aids_readers where study_aid_id 
in
 (
select s.id, s.title , p.name , s.type 
from study_aids s, profiles p 
where s.author_id = p.user_id and p.country_id = '30' and date(s.created_at) >= '2015-01-01' )
```

I am trying to achieve list of ids from study_aids_readers table which are present in study_aids tables and then compare the ids against the profiles those created the study aids from profiles tables.
Please help me out or ask me for further information in case.

Answer (score 1):

The list of `in` in MySQL can only have one column.

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
select study_aid_id
from study_aids_readers
where study_aid_id in (select s.id
                       from study_aids s join
                            profiles p 
                            on s.author_id = p.user_id 
                       where p.country_id = '30' and date(s.created_at) >= '2015-01-01'
                      );
```

Also note the use of proper explicit `join` syntax.